# The texture appears fine when in the preview mode but some white parts appear when I render the Scene in blender

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv

So I have this room scene in which I have used geo-scatter for the vegetation.
[image: Material Previewstrong text]

All the textures appear Fine and There is no White space and the mesh is joined without separation.

But during the render something like this happens.
[image: Rendered Image]

As you can see there are some white lines at the corner edges and the floor. Any help  is appreciated.

Comment: Found it, there was a problem with the displacement node of my textures.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on what exact steps you took to resolve your problem?